# How to trap right-click event?

Tags: javascript, html

What is the way to trap a right-click event on a document element? I could not find any event handlers anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right-click is special on many browsers, triggering the `contextmenu` event rather than a `click` event. Some browsers let you prevent the default behavior, some (Opera, for instance) do not. More here: http://unixpapa.com/js/mouse.html

**EDIT:** Rereading that page (it'd been a while), it looks like `mousedown` and `mouseup` are even more reliable than `contextmenu` (although all major browsers trigger `contextmenu`). `click`, on the other hand, doesn't appear to happen at all, on any significant browser.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is event "oncontextmenu", you can hook it.

Here is the jQuery based contextmenu handler,

http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/

PS:It doesn't work in My Opera though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the

**[window.oncontextmenu](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.oncontextmenu)**

> An event handler property for
>   right-click events on the window.

If you need to disable the right click in a page then you can use something like this

```
window.oncontextmenu = function () {
   return false;
}
```

or if you need to give your own custom context menu then also you can code inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the click or mousedown/up event. From [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html):

```
function doSomething(e) {
    var rightclick;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.which) rightclick = (e.which == 3);
    else if (e.button) rightclick = (e.button == 2);
    alert('Rightclick: ' + rightclick); // true or false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The event has a "button" attrubute
so lmb is 0
mmb is 1
rmb is 2

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_button.asp